# How to view DICOM files in android

Tags: android

I searched a lot on google and stackoverflow but doesnt help all the solutions had not working.please help me for that.how can view .dcm file android.
tried this [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/droid-dicom-viewer/source) its not working still.

It giving me this exception

```
E/ERROR: java.io.IOException: DICOM JPEG compression not yet supported
```

Comment: `its not working still.` how exactly it is not working?

Comment: edited check the question

Comment: ok, the error is clear that lib does not support JPEG compression. There are some other libraries, but you can't ask to find you a library here. You can google by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The open source [Imebra](https://imebra.com) library supports the jpeg compression and comes with a Jar that includes the native pre-compiled C++ code for several architectures.

Disclosure: I'm the author of Imebra.

Comment: thanks for your reply.but how i can use this is there is any demo?

Comment: how can i include and use this jar?

Comment: https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/html/quick_tour.html

Comment: No implementation found for long com.imebra.imebraJNI.CodecFactory_load__SWIG_3(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_imebra_imebraJNI_CodecFactory_1load_1_1SWIG_13 and Java_com_imebra_imebraJNI_CodecFactory_1load_1_1SWIG_13__Ljava_lang_String_2) got this error on first line

Comment: error on this line DataSet loadedDataSet = CodecFactory.load(fileName);

Comment: can't load the dataset in andriod please help.:)

Comment: imbera supports the some file to open but it not supported to other why?